# Arrays vs. Structs C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, struct

I don't seem to understand why I'm getting a:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

When inputting my 'movies' into the movie struct. Are there any blaring obvious logic errors here or what?

Along with the segmentation fault my for loop within the void set_movies() seems to only be returning 4 prompts for movies when it should be returning 5 due to the #define NUM_MOVIES 5.

Thanks a ton!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#define NUM_MOVIES 5

using namespace std;

struct movie{
   string name[];
   double copies[];
   double rating[];
   string description[];
   string genre[];
} films [NUM_MOVIES];

void set_movies();
int which_movies_to_view();
int get_movies();
int rent_movie();
int printmovie();
int choice;

int main(){
    set_movies();
    which_movies_to_view();
    get_movies();
    rent_movie();

    return 0;
}

void set_movies(){
    movie set;

    for(int i=0; i<NUM_MOVIES; i++){
        cout << "Enter movie title: " << endl;
        cin >> set.name[i];
        cout << "Enter how many copies: " << endl;
        cin >> set.copies[i];
        cout << "Enter the rating: " << endl;
        cin >> set.rating[i];
        cout << "Enter a description: " << endl;
        cin >> set.description[i];
        cout << "Enter the genre: " << endl;
        cin >> set.genre[i];
    }
}

int which_movies_to_view(){
    movie set;

    cout << "  " << set.name[1] << set.name[2] << set.name[3] << set.name[4] << set.name[5] << endl;
    cout << "Which movie would you like to view?: [1, 2, 3, 4, or 5]" << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    return choice;
}

int get_movies(){

    movie set;

    if(choice == 1){
       cout << set.name[1] << endl;
    }
    if(choice == 2){
       cout << set.name[2] << endl;
    }
    if(choice == 3){
       cout << set.name[3] << endl;
    }
    if(choice == 4){
       cout << set.name[4] << endl;
    }
    if(choice == 5){
       cout << set.name[5] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int printmovie(){

    int n;
    for(int n = 0; n<NUM_MOVIES; n++)
    cout << films[n].name;
    cout << films[n].copies;
    cout << films[n].rating;
    cout << films[n].description;
    cout << films[n].genre;

    return 0;
}

int rent_movie(){
    movie set;

    if(choice == 1){
            set.copies[0] - 1;
            cout << set.copies[0] << " copies left!" << endl;
    }
    if(choice == 2){
            set.copies[1] - 1;
            cout << set.copies[1] << " copies left!" << endl;
    }
    if(choice == 3){
            set.copies[2] - 1;
            cout << set.copies[2] << " copies left!" << endl;
    }
    if(choice == 4){
            set.copies[3] - 1;
            cout << set.copies[3] << " copies left!" << endl;
    }
    if(choice == 5){
            set.copies[4] - 1;
            cout << set.copies[4] << " copies left!" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're writing to uninitialized memory – classic [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: How can the compiler know how many bytes to reserve when you declare `double copies[]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are declaring the members of your struct as empty arrays, but also declaring an array of those structs.

I think you actually want this:

```
struct movie{
   string name;
   double copies;
   double rating;
   string description;
   string genre;
} films [NUM_MOVIES];
```

And then use `films[i].movie`, `films[i].copies`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

“string name[];” this defines empty array, then when you write to "set.name[i]", it causes core dump. So to other memebers of struct movie.

Actually, you can use gdb to read core file, that will show you where core dump happened.

Answer (score 1):

The only function in which you have correctly used your data structure is `printmovie()`.  Everywhere else where you use things like `set.name[i]` is incorrect.  Furthermore, you should remove the `[]` from the definitions inside your struct.  Otherwise I believe that they are treated as pointer types.

Answer (score 1):

Your `struct` could look this:

```
struct Movie
{
   std::string name;
   unsigned int copies;
   double rating;
   std::string description;
   std::string genre;
};
```

and since you are using C++ and you probably want to be your list of movies flexible in size, you should use `std::vector` instead of C-style array:

```
std::vector<Movie> movies;
```

Then you can simply add new movies into this `vector` by using its `push_back` method:

```
Movie m;
// set m's data members here
movies.push_back(m);
```

And later when you want to access these movies, you can treat it just like an array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < movies.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << movies[i].name << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not declaring array's size in movie struct.
Remember that C++ inherits many features from C, who forces to declare how many memory you want to allocate at the beginning of each functions.